# Mobile website viewport exact width issue

Tags: html, mobile, width, viewport

I've a website that I'm building which is 700px width on desktops and mobile. On the desktop the 700px div is centred. On mobile the 700px div just needs to fill the screen.

Test code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=700" />
    <style>
        div#wrapper
        {
            width:700px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
         <img src="/test.jpg" alt="Test image 700px width in 100px strips" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine across desktop browsers and most mobile phones. **However on my daughters cheapo smartphone the browser zooms right in and only displays about 350px.**

How should I approach this issue. You would think that it would be an easy situation to resolve but it's proving not too be! Messing about with the other meta tag attributes (initial zoom etc) has no effect on this particular smartphone.

The Huawei phones browser is Agent: Modzilla/5.0(Linux; U; Andriod 4.2.2;en-gb;HUAWEI Y330-U01 Build/HuaweiY330-U01)AppleWebKit/534.30(KHTML, likeGecko)Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Comment: instead of hard coding the width of image use media query - 
The below website narrates some standard sizes
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices

and the next link have got few more size specific media query
http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

Comment: The issue I think is resolved with setting width as a % rather than fixed pixel width. But setting the width differently for the desktop version with a media query.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots and url for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

**Explanation:**

A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Here is an example of a web page without the viewport meta tag, and the same web page with the viewport meta tag:

**Demo**

- [Without view port](http://www.w3schools.com/css/example_withoutviewport.htm)
- [With view port](http://www.w3schools.com/css/example_withviewport.htm)

Read this - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ and this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android device to verify this, but perhaps this would be solved with a relative width and a [maximum width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#wrapper
    {
        width:100%;
        max-width:700px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
</style>
```

`max-width` overrides `width` when its conditions are met, so a smaller display like that on your daughter's phone should use a full width while a larger display would only be 700 pixels wide.

(I added the `type` attribute to your `<style>` tag for completeness. Your code should render just fine without it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will solve your problem

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

instead of

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set your CSS width to 100%, not 700px. It's generally best to avoid hardcoding dimensions when possible. Also as suggested by another answer, max-width could be useful as it overrides width when specified. 
You could then use screen size media queries(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to put a border div around the image on large displays.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below link inside the head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Style Sheet

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px)//media query for the resolution below 700px {
    div#wrapper
        {
            width:100%;// this will took full width
        }
}
</style>
```